# How to make rollup.js build a react library on installing (yarn add ssh://git@my-repo-url)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollupjs

I've created a private react library (git repo) with **rollup.js**, and it's installing correctly with the command `yarn add ssh://git@my-repo-url` but it's not building (creating build/dist in *node_modules/library-folder*) on installing. How can I fix it? What's the 'magic' behind the alternative [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library#development). Is **npm** behind this?

Here is my **rollup.con.js**:

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

import packageJson from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "./src/components/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript(),
    postcss()
  ]
};
```

and my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "my-ui-lib",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "module": "./build/index.es.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "build": "rollup -c",
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^19.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.2.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.2.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.2.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.2.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.7",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.2.9",
    "postcss": "^8.3.2",
    "rollup": "^2.51.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any specialty packages/boilerplate code to install from a local/private github repo. Just follow these simple steps:

1.) Make sure you're using the correct github repo:
`git+ssh://git@github.com/<github_username>/<github_repo>`

`<github_username>` should be your github username

`<github_repo>` should be the name of your github repository

2.) Prep your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json) with the necessary fields, but most importantly add a `prepare` or `prepublish` script to your [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts) in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@example/my-package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My package description.",
  // 'main' and 'module' are useful for bundlers (like webpack) to know which version to default import
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "esm/index.mjs",
  // 'sideEffects' is optional, let's bundlers (like webpack) know that it's tree-shakeable
  "sideEffects": false,
  "homepage": "https://github.com/<github_username>/<github_repo>#readme",
  // 'files' is required to let your package manager know what should be installed in node_modules
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "index.d.ts",
    "decrypt/index.js",
    "decrypt/index.d.ts",
    "encrypt/index.js",
    "encrypt/index.d.ts",
    "esm"
  ],
  // 'types' is optional, but useful for typescript typings
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  // 'exports' is optional, but useful for submodule imports
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js",
    "./decrypt": "./decrypt/index.js",
    "./encrypt": "./encrypt/index.js",
    "./esm": "./esm/index.mjs",
    "./esm/decrypt": "./esm/decrypt/index.mjs",
    "./esm/encrypt": "./esm/encrypt/index.mjs"
  },
  // 'scripts' will be leveraged by adding a 'prepare' or `prepublish` script to let the package manager know what to run during dependency installation
  "scripts": {
    "build": tsc --p ./ts/tsconfig.cjs.json && ts-node ./utils/compress.ts",
    "build:esm": "rollup -c",
    "lint": "eslint ./ --ext .ts,.js && tsd",
    "prepare": "npm run build && npm run build:esm",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.json --coverage",
  },
  // 'repository' is optional, but useful to tell developers/remote websites (like npmjs) where your code resides
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.<github_username>/<github_repo>.git"
  },
  "author": "Firstname Lastname",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/<github_username>/<github_repo>/issues"
  },
  // 'engines' is highly recommended as it lets the package manager know which versions of node will be able to run the package without issues
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12"
  },
  "devDependencies": { ... },
}
```

3.) Install the package using `npm` or `yarn`:

```sh
# with npm
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com/<github_username>/<github_repo>

# or with yarn
yarn add git+ssh://git@github.com/<github_username>/<github_repo>
```

4.) Import the package by the **name** specified in the `package.json`:

```js
const example = require("@example/my-package");
// import example from "@example/my-package";

...etc
```

---

Example package repo:
https://github.com/mattcarlotta/example-env

Example using package repo:
https://github.com/mattcarlotta/example-using-repo

Result:
[image]